# Feature extraction per fold with Scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection

for a machine learning experiment I have to perform feature selection. I have no division in training and test set because of 10-fold cross validation. Someone told me that I have to do the feature selection per fold. But I have no idea how to do that. Here is a part of my code.

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(instances) # No train/ test set, because we'll use 10-fold cross validation
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False) 
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X) # To make sure everything is on the same scale

enc = LabelEncoder()
y = enc.fit_transform(labels)

#feature selection
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, mutual_info_classif
feat_sel = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=200) 
X_fs = feat_sel.fit_transform(X_scaled, y)

#train a classifier
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
y_pred = model_selection.cross_val_predict(clf, X_fs, y, cv=10)
```

Can someone help me with the selection per fold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering the second question that you posted.**

You can use cross validation and see the results:

Do:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, mutual_info_classif, RFECV
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline        
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np

feat_sel = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=200) 

clf = MultinomialNB()
pipe = Pipeline([('mutual_info',feat_sel), ('naive_bayes',clf)])

scores = cross_val_score(pipe, X_scaled, y, cv =10, scoring = 'accuracy')
print(np.mean(scores))
```

Comment: Am I right to say that I don't need to do a `pipe.fit()` anymore?

Comment: @Bambi yes yes of course no need any more. cross_val_scores does eveything when you call it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pipeline`, join the feature selector and the classifier into a pipeline and cross-validate the pipeline.

Reference: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Comment: I edited it with pipeline code. Now my accuracy is approximately 10% higher then when I did'nt use the pipeline. Is this possible?

Comment: Sera's comment to your answer provides the solution.